# Mac OSX, Apple rejected Unity app. Codesign issue?

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine

We've made a game with Unity 5, which runs without any problems on Mac OSX. But for the Mac OSX App Store from Apple, the game must be codesigned.
I've done that a lot of times in the past and there I didn't have problems. But I have made a clean install of OSX on the Mac a few weeks ago. I installed all the certificates and they seem to work. But I can't check in the terminal, which codesign commands I used in the past, and there maybe the problem...

In Unity I build the app with the Mac Appstore Validation.
Then I edit the info.plist, add the icons, create the entitlements-file (do all which was listed in several documents) and go to the terminal.
There I type in the directory of the app:

```
chmod -R a+xr “APPNAME.app"

codesign -f -v -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: COMPANY-NAME" "APPNAME.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx/libmono.0.dylib"

codesign -f --deep -s '3rd Party Mac Developer Application: COMPANY-NAME' --entitlements "APPNAME.entitlements" "APPNAME.app"

productbuild --component "APPNAME.app" /Applications --sign "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: COMPANY-NAME" "APPNAME.pkg"
```

Everything works fine, even with the `libmono.0.dylib`. There I get the result that the existing codesigning will be replaced. I am not sure, but I had in mind, that we have codesigned 3 lines in the past, but we didn't have used any more Frameworks or Plugins now.

Then I test the pkg. I install it and was asked about the login-details and I login with a iTunesConnect testuser-account. The app will be installed and when I try to run it, it will be closed after a few seconds. Then something curious happens. I must login again with the testuser and after that the game starts without problem (without trying to start it again!)

I upload the pkg with the ApplicationLoader 3.1 (3.6 didn't work, because it says to me, that I can't submit an IPA-file, even it is a pkg, a lot have that problem and use an old version of the loader) and that worked too. But I got the result of Apple with the rejection: "...launched app and immediately stopped from launching." So they can't start it.

When I check the codesigned app with `spctl -a -t exec -vv <APPNAME>` I got the result:

```
<APPNAME>: rejected
...
```

But I didn't know where I've done the mistake?!

Does anyone has an idea of what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You mean in the savety case to recreate the certificates? I am sure, that I have done that when setup the Mac new, but if there can't happen any wrong, I can do it again for going sure...
Edit: I've created new certificates for that mac and try to codesign again. When I make the check with `spctl -a -t exec -vv <APPNAME>` I got the rejected again.

For the Mac OSX App Store I only need the certificates
3rd Party Mac Developer Application
3rd Party Mac Developer Installer
Mac OS Developer

And in the certificates (dev area at developer.apple.com) I have additional:
Mac App Distribution
Mac Installer Distribution